# How to do swift availability checking on watchOS 3

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, watchos, watchos-3

I'm having an interesting problem with `watchOS 3` and `watchOS 2`. In my `ComplicationController` I want to support both `watchOS 3` and `watchOS 2.` When creating the complication templates I'm checking if the user is running `watchOS 3`. If he is I will allow an `.ExtraLarge` complication to be used, otherwise this option is not available.

I'm using the `#available` syntax, but the app fails to even launch on `watchOS 2` because of a missing framework. Here is my code:

```
if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 3.0, *) {
   if complicationFamily == .ExtraLarge {
      let extraLarge = CLKComplicationTemplateExtraLargeSimpleText()
      extraLarge.textProvider = simpleTextProvider

      return extraLarge
   } else {
      return nil
   }
} else {
   return nil
}
```

When I run on `watchOS 2` this is the error I get:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CLKComplicationTemplateExtraLargeSimpleText
  Referenced from: /Users/asdf/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/48D00565-3BA5-4851-B249-5818BA060716/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1ACF1C41-9D9E-4AB6-9D49-767A067AE968/WatchKit App.app/PlugIns/WatchKit Extension.appex/WatchKit Extension
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS 2.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/ClockKit.framework/ClockKit
```

Has anyone else had issues deploying to both `watchOS 3` and `watchOS 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with help from a post on the Apple Developer Forums. I needed to add the `ClockKit.framework` to the linked binaries and set its status to `Optional`. Now everything works as expected on `watchOS 2`.

Here's the post:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61712